# How do I set the width of a component in my React web-app based off the output of a variable

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a component which I'm attempting to set the width of based off the result of a variable.

The variable returns a number between 1 and 100, and as such I want to set the width to reflect the result of the variable.

However, despite being able to render the result within the component, I can't set the width. This is the first time I've tried to conditionally render the width of a React component before, so figure I'm doing something obvious wrong.

Here's the render function in question:

```
const fetchLoans = this.state.debts.map(debt => {

      const loanBalance = debt.balance
      const loanBorrowed = debt.borrowed
      const loanSum = Math.round(loanBalance / loanBorrowed * 100)

      return (<div className="individual-loan-amount-outstanding" key={debt._id}>

        <div className="individual-loan-amount-bar">

          <div className="individual-loan-amount-indicator" style={{ width: {loanSum} }}>{loanSum}%</div>

        </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

As you can hopefully see, I'm attempting to set the 'width' based off the result of 'loanSum'.

I can render 'loanSum' in the div, but not with the width.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't put the curly brackets around `loanSum`, so your line should be:

```
<div className="individual-loan-amount-indicator" style={{ width: loanSum }}>{loanSum}%</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value in % that's how i did it

```
<div className="individual-loan-amount-indicator" style={{ width: `${loanSum}%` }}>{loanSum}%</div>
```